# This a href killing me

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-lists, nav

I am doing myself a website but while on developing I got on my first problem.
Links are not working for some reason.
None of them are working.

```html
<nav class="cd-3d-nav js-cd-3d-nav" id="cd-3d-nav">
  <ul class="cd-3d-nav__list">
    <li class="cd-3d-nav__item cd-3d-nav__item--selected">
      <a href="pocetna.html">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--md">
                            <i class="lni-emoji-happy"></i>
                        </svg>
        <span>O meni</span >
                    </a>
                </li>
    
                <li class="cd-3d-nav__item">
                    <a href="kontakt.html">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--md">
                            <i class="lni-briefcase"></i>
                        </svg>
                        <span>Projekti</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="cd-3d-nav__item">
      <a href="#2">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--md">
    
                            <i class="lni-seo-monitoring"></i>
                        </svg>
        <span>Usluge</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cd-3d-nav__item">
      <a href="kontakt.html">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--md">
    
                            <i class="lni-phone-handset"></i>
                        </svg>
        <span>Kontakt</span>
      </a>
    </li>


  </ul>

  <span class="cd-3d-nav__marker cd-3d-nav__marker--col-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</nav>
```

Comment: What's the problem? They seem to be working fine.

Comment: Define "not working". Are the links broken (page not found), or they don't redirect whatsoever?

Comment: They are not leading to other page.Not showing anything

Comment: @M4rio1712 there could be some Javascript messing things up then. Try excluding your current Javascript code from the website, and try again. If the links work after that, then it is a problem with your Javascript code.

Comment: @AnisR. tried still not working.

Comment: *They are not leading to other page* what page are they leading to? Give us an example of the link you click and the url it goes to please -  it is hard to debug **not working** as that can cover a multitude of things

Comment: Please include your folder structure, this sounds like an issue with the url path and the location of the file you're trying to access not matching.

Comment: Tried even like this <a href="../html/kontakt.html">

Not working.

When I click on link nothing happens.

Comment: Here are files if someone can debug it. Thanks <3. 


https://gofile.io/?c=Vr3BQ6

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the html files in the same directory as the index.html file. They will work like a charm. Good luck.